Calling a powershell script without specifying the full path of the file
I have got a wrapper script which calls another powershell script that then calls a bicep deployment, I would like to implement a solution where I am not specifying the path of the file, as the solution would be moved onto github actions, with the current setup I have hardcoded the paths
.\deploy.ps1 `
    -DeploymentResourceGroup 'my-rg' `
    -TemplateFile 'C:\A\B\C\D\main.bicep' `
    -ParameterFile 'C:\A\B\C\D\E\envs\dev.json' `
    -rbacTemplateFile 'C:\A\B\C\D\rbac_roles.bicep' `

I have tried to change it to the format below without any luck, I get an error that the file cannot be found
    -TemplateFile '.\.\.\.\.\main.bicep' 

deploy.ps1 has the following code
`az deployment group create --resource-group $resourcegroupName --template-file $rbacTemplateFile --parameters $rbacParameterFile `

I have done it like this as I do not want to be passing path to the code all the time, but since the paths are static have it within a wrapper script.

A single dot . means "the current directory" - do you mean two dots .. instead for the parent directory? If you add the folder structure where the *.ps1 and bicep template live it'll be easier to give help working out what the relative path should be...

What do you do with $TemplateFile inside the deploy.ps1 script? If you pass it off to another program you might want to call Convert-Path or Resolve-Path first

I removed my answer because it didn't address the issue with the bicep files.
